# VUEJS remove Element From Lists?

Tags: vue.js

it is possible to remove specific element from lists. i tried this functions for remove element

> pop() = remove last element
>
> $remove(index) = not remove any element from lists
>
> remove( index ) = undefined function
>
> unshift( index ) = add new and empty element
>
> splice( index )  = remove all element from index

please help me to remove specific element from lists.

below is my js code

```
var example2 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-2',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' },
      { message: 'Bar1' },
      { message: 'Bar2' },
      { message: 'Bar3' },
      { message: 'Bar4' }
    ]
  },
  methods : {
    removeElement : function(index){
        this.items.$remove(index);
    }
  }
})
```

below is my HTML code

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="(key, item) in items">
    {{ item.message }}
    <button v-on:click="removeElement(key)">remove</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Lukasz Wiktor has the right answer for Vue version 2.2.0+. For Vue.js 2 : v-for="(key, item) in items" must be v-for="(item, index) in items" and for Vue.js 2.2.0+ you need the key attribute : <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item"> https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.2.0?utm_campaign=Revue%20newsletter&utm_medium=Newsletter&utm_source=revue

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`$remove` is deprecated in Vue.js 2.0 and replaced by `splice` as stated in the docs. Make sure you add the 2nd parameter of `splice` for it to work.

[Migration From Vue 1.x - 2.0](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Array-prototype-remove-removed)

```
methods: {
  removeElement: function (index) {
    this.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

You can use [Vue.delete](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete) if your Vue version is 2.2.0+

```
Vue.delete(this.items, index);
```

Comment: I used this (`Vue.delete(state.items, 'someitem')`) when using the vuex store since `state` does not have a `$delete` or `delete` method.

Answer (score 24):

The `$.remove` feature has been replaced with `$.delete`.

You can call it like so:

`this.$delete(this.someItems, itemIndex)`.

It works on `Object` as well as `Array`. With objects, you need to use a keyed object. With arrays, you pass in the index of the item you want to delete.

Here is a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/james2doyle/386w72nn/

*EDIT*

I added an example for an array as well

Comment: I've tried this.$delete on a Array, it makes appropriate value "undefined", but doesn't remove it from the list.

Comment: Can't use Vue developer tools on JS fiddle. But in my case it was in the Vue dev tools where I've noticed that array became something like: `['A', undefined, 'B', 'C']`, after I've used `this.$delete()`. In the visual UI all seemed Ok, though.

P.S.: with `myArray.splice(index, 1)` there was no such issue. I.e., I've got it right both in the UI and in the Vue Dev Tools.

Comment: this removed my warning about mutating in store state, thanks

Answer (score 17):

$delete can use inline in @click:

```
<ul id="example">
   <li v-for="(item, key) in items">
       {{ item.message }}
       <button @click="$delete(items, key)">remove</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-delete

Comment: Thanks for that easy solution.
This should be the accepted answer as this is just the smartest way to solve it imho.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should fix the `methods` key.

Then, you should pass the item to the `$remove` method, not the `index`. [[ref]](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats)

https://jsfiddle.net/790og9w6/

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wonders: $delete has been removed in VueJS 3 ( https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#removed-apis ). Now it is possible to use javascripts native splice(index, count of objects to be deleted).