# unable to get correct user id to remove list-element in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vue.js

I am trying to delete a user from the database by select the user from a list, and then click a button to remove the user. I've tried to implement the method to remove the user, but I am unable to get the id from the selected user.

Does anyone know how I can access the user id to the selected user within the removeUser method?

my html code:

```
<template id="user-template">
    <div>
        <ul class="collection">
            <a class=" collection-item avatar" v-for="user in users" v-on:click="userClicked(user, $event)">
                <span class="name">{{ user.firstName }}</span>
            </a>
        </ul>

        <div id="removeUser" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class=" modal-action modal-close btn-flat" v-on:click="removeUser">yes</a>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <a class="btn-floating red" data-target="removeUser"></a>
  <user @selected-user="setSelected"></user>
</div>
```

My vue component:

```
user: {
    template: '#user-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            users: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        removeUser: function (user) {
            this.$http.delete('/user/', user).then(function (data) {
            this.users.$remove(user)
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
<a class=" collection-item avatar" v-for="(user, index) in users"
   :key="user" v-on:click="userClicked(user, index, $event)">

user: {
    template: '#user-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            users: [],
            userSelected: { id: -1, index: -1 }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        userClicked: function (user, index, event) {
            this.userSelected.id = user.id;//If user has an id property
            this.userSelected.index = index;
        });
        removeUser: function () {
            if( this.userSelected.id > -1 ) {
                this.$http.delete('/user/' + this.userSelected.id).then(function (data) {
                this.users.splice(this.userSelected.index, 1);
                this.userSelected.id = -1;
                this.userSelected.index = -1;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And you can disable remove button if no user selected :

```
<div :disabled="userSelected.id === -1" id="removeUser" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <a class=" modal-action modal-close btn-flat" v-on:click="removeUser">yes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you don't want to use index to remove the user in the users array, you can use the id :

```
methods: {
   removeUserWithId: function( id ) {
       for( var i = 0, length = this.users.length; i < length; i++ ) {
           if( this.users[i].id === id ) {
              this.users.splice(i, 1);
              return;
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Note :

key is required in v-for since Vue 2.2.0+ [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.2.0?utm_campaign=Revue%20newsletter&utm_medium=Newsletter&utm_source=revue)

$remove is deprecated : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459010/vuejs-remove-element-from-lists)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.
There was however a problem with the api path, it should have a plus instead of a comma. like this: delete('/user/' + this.userSelected.id)