# Vuejs, removing element from nested lists

Tags: list, vue.js, for-loop

This is a followup question on [VUEJS remove Element From Lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459010/vuejs-remove-element-from-lists), where they give various methods (this.$remove, splice, this.$delete) for dynamically removing a element from a list. I was trying to understand how to apply this to a nested loop; here's mine in three+ levels, somewhat stripped-down:

```
<template v-for="(labtype,index) in labIRlist">
  <template v-for="(lab,index2) in labtype">
    <tr v-for="(IR,index3) in lab.irs" :key="IR.irn">
      <td><p>{{ lab.hidtxt }}_{{ lab.mnem }}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{ lab.PNL }}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{ IR.provider}} {{ IR.psurv }}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{ IR.year }}-{{ IR.eventno }}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{ IR.analytes }}</p></td>
      <td><p>
        <button type="button" 
          @click="deleteIR(IR.irn,index,index2,index3)">
            DELETE
        </button>
      </p></td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</template>
```

Then there's Javascript for the deletion

```
methods: {
  deleteIR: function(IRNum,index,index2,index3) {
    // okay, delete!
    //... code to do something at the database...
    alert('IR successfully deleted!')
    // don't show the deleted IR any more
    this.labIRlist[index][index2].irs.splice(index3,1);
  },
```

Awful, but I didn't know how to identify the correct element. And it still didn't work (AFAIK it does nothing, no change visible to the row). How should this be done - don't we know the right element from where deleteIR was called?

Comment: Could you add a demo for this? A codesandbox or something? Or at least show us a part of the data you have in `labIRlist`

Comment: Also `still doesn't work` is not helpful. What does the function do currently? Nothing, throw an error, delete wrong line or what?

Comment: Edited: it does nothing as far as I can see.

Comment: @AJT82 Perhaps I should have left out the comment that it didn't work - because my real question is, What is the better way to handle deleting an element within multiple loops?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the better way to handle deleting an element within multiple
> loops?

First of all, looking at how your template is built, we can assume that your data looks something like this:

```js
  labIRlist: [
    [
      {
        hidtxt: "TEXT 1",
        irs: [{ provider: "provider1" }, { provider: "provider11" }],
        irn: "irn1",
      },
      {
        hidtxt: "TEXT 2",
        irs: [
          { provider: "provider2" },
          { provider: "provider22" },
          { provider: "provider222" },
        ],
        irn: "irn2",
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        hidtxt: "TEXT 3",
        irs: [{ provider: "provider3" }],
        irn: "irn3",
      },
    ],
  ],
```

If you want to delete one item from the nested `irs` array, all you need to do is to pass the `irs` array and the index of the item you want to delete, no need to do the whole path you are doing currently:

```js
this.labIRlist[index][index2].irs.splice(index3,1);
```

So change your template to:

```html
<button type="button" @click="deleteIR(lab.irs, index3)">
```

And the delete function is then simply:

```js
deleteIR(IRS, index) {
  IRS.splice(index, 1);
}
```

**A [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-ptolemy-h28fl?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) for your reference**

PS. Please always share a bit of your data when posting questions like this. Much easier to answer when not needing to create your own sample data like I did here.

Comment: Ah! That's exactly what I was asking: A way to address the data from the bottom of the loop directly. Thanks!

Comment: I see now what you mean by providing data. Thanks again.

Comment: OK Great, glad I could help! :)